# Overload JDBC driver

Tags: java, jdbc

I have a proprietary JDBC driver provided by an editor for their product.
Problem is, I need to use that driver in another product which does not allow me to pass JDBC properties. And of course I am required to pass some properties.

So my idea is to create a custom driver that would act as a wrapper to the JDBC driver that I need to use; the only twist would be that the custom driver I build, would pass those properties (hardcoded).

What would be the best way to achieve that? Just extend the original driver and overload the connection methods?

Ugly solution I know, but no choice at this point.

Comment: Your JDBC driver doesn't allow passing those properties in the connection URL?

Comment: Unfortunately no, for two reasons. 
1 - These properties can only be passed with a Properties object which I cannot do with the querying tool I am trying to setup
2 - The querying tool itself does not allow to use ? and & in their JDBC URL.... Which is the dumbest thing I've seen :D